# Help on require answer $\int_0^1\frac{2}{[1+x+(-\phi)^{-n}(1-x)]^2}dx=\frac{1}{-{\phi}F_n+F_{n+1}+1}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fibonacci-numbers

$\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$

$F_0=0$, $F_1=1$ ;$F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ ; Fibonacci numbers **(0,1,1,2,3,5,...)**

Show that,

$$\int_0^1\frac{2}{[1+x+(-\phi)^{-n}(1-x)]^2}dx=\frac{1}{-{\phi}F_n+F_{n+1}+1}$$

---

Trying to work out...

$$\int_0^1\frac{2}{[1+x+(-\phi)^{-n}(1-x)]^2}dx=\frac{-2}{1-(-\phi)^{-n}}\left[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{1+(-\phi)^{-n}}\right]$$

$$=-\frac{1+(-\phi)^{-n}-2}{1-(-\phi)^{-2n}}$$

This is correct, but it is not getting me to the proposed answer, what do I need to do to get the require answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linear difference equation $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$, let $F_n=r^n$. Then $r^{n+1}=r^n+r^{n-1}$ or $r^{n-1}(r^2-r-1)=0$. Solution of the characteristic equation is $r=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}2$, so $r\in\{\phi,-1/\phi\}$. Since this is a linear homogeneous difference equation, superposition works, so $F_n=c_1\phi^n+c_2\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n$. Then
$$F_0=c_1+c_2=0$$
$$F_1=\phi c_1-\frac1{\phi}c_2=1$$
Solving, $c_1=-c_2=1/\sqrt5$, so
$$F_n=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^n-\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n\right)$$
Checking, we see that $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and
$$\begin{align}F_{n+1}-F_n-F_{n-1}&=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^{n+1}-\phi^n-\phi^{n-1}-\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^{n+1}+\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n+\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^{n-1}(\phi^2-\phi-1)-\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^{n-1}\left(\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^2-\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)-1\right)\right)\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^{n-1}(0)-\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^{n-1}(0)\right)=0\end{align}$$
Then $$\begin{align}F_{n+1}-\phi F_n&=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^{n+1}-\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^{n+1}-\phi^{n+1}-\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n\left(\frac1{\phi}+\phi\right)=\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n\end{align}$$
And then
$$\begin{align}-\frac{1+(-\phi)^{-n}-2}{1-(-\phi)^{-2n}}&=\frac{1-\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n}{\left(1+\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n\right)\left(1-\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n\right)}\\
&=\frac1{1+\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n}=\frac1{1+F_{n+1}-\phi F_n}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the explicit formula for Fn, as opposed to the recursive formula.

Comment: I think answers should be more self-contained. What is the explicit formula?

Comment: @fonini Hmmm... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Comment: I know what the closed form is, and I know where to look if I forget those signs. But other people might not know.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$\frac{-2}{1-(-\phi)^{-n}}\left[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{1+(-\phi)^{-n}}\right]=\frac{1}{1+(-\phi)^{-n}}$$
$\therefore$ Need to prove by induction that $(-\phi)^{-n}=-{\phi}F_{n}+F_{n+1}$, for nonnegative integer n